# Javascript nested JSON object not adding outermost values to stack

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I am new to JS and attempting to write a recursive function to grab operator and number data from a JSON object of unknown depth for an elementary calculator. I am very close(I think) but the "opStack.push(obj.op)" is not working on the outermost object. It is, however, working on the nested elements.Clearly, I must be missing something obvious because this seems straightforward.

So for the test case '{"op": "add", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "expr" : {"op" : "subtract", "number" : 3}}}' ; 
the expected result would be that my stack contains {add,add,subtract,3} but instead it contains {add,subtract,3}

This is the code in Question:

```
 // function used for iterating nested objects and adding them to the stack
    function iterStore(obj){
        if(!(obj.number)){
            opStack.push(obj.op);
            iterStore(obj.expr);
        }else{
            opStack.push(obj.op);
            opStack.push(obj.number)
            return true;
            }
        }
```

This is the entire code base including the stack impl:

```
var initial=0;
var opStack = new Stack();
    // Stack implementation
    function Stack(){
    let items=[];
    // add element to last index of array
    this.push = function(value){
       items.push(value);
    };
    // return last index of array
    this.pop=function(){
        return items.pop();
    };
    // displays but doesn't remove last index
    this.peek = function(){
        return items[items.length-1];
    };
    //checks for empty list returns boolean
    this.isEmpty = function(){
        return items.length==0;
    };
    // returns size of stack
    this.size=function(){
        return items.length;
    };
    //clears all values from stack
    this.clear = function(){
        console.log("Stack cleared")
         items=[];
    };
    this.print = function(){
        console.log(items);
    };
}
// function used for iterating nested objects and adding them to the stack
function iterStore(obj){
    if(!(obj.number)){
        opStack.push(obj.op);
        iterStore(obj.expr);
    }else{
        opStack.push(obj.op);
        opStack.push(obj.number)
        return true;
        }
    }
// function to take the data in stack and perform the operations
function operations(inStack){
    var tempNum=inStack.pop();

    while(inStack.length>0){
        var oper=inStack.pop();

        if(oper.toLowerCase()=="add"){
            initial=initial+tempNum;
            tempNum=intital
        }else if(oper.toLowerCase()=="subtract"){
            initial=initial-tempNum;
            tempNum=initial;
        }
    }
}
// final function to call 
function calc(inString){
    var parsed = JSON.parse(inString);
    iterStore(parsed);
    operations(opStack);
    console.log(initial);

}
// Test Cases
var test='{"op": "subtract", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}'; 
var test1='{"op": "add", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "expr" : {"op" : "subtract", "number" : 3}}}' ; 
var test2='{"op" : "add", "number" : 19}';
```

Comment: The condition `!(obj.number)` will also be true when `obj.number` exists, but is "falsy", like 0. Instead do `!('number' in obj)`. But your question does not show enough of your code to reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: What are the expected results from your test cases?

Comment: the above code is not storing values in opStack object, replace `items` by `this.items` and remove `let`.

Comment: I added a test case and example of my desired output vs actual output. Sorry for not clarifying initially. The opStack is storing all of the values other than the outermost "op" which is what is giving me grief.